# Android String Array Manipulation

Tags: android

I have a lengthy string in my Android program.
What I need is, I need to split each word of that string and copy that each word to a new String Array.
For eg: If the string is "I did android program" and the string array is named my_array then each index should contain values like:

```
my_array[0] = I
my_array[1] = did
my_array[2] = Android
my_array[3] = Program
```

A part of program which I did looks like this:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(result,"|");
Toast.makeText(appointment.this, st.nextToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
while(st.hasMoreTokens())
{
String n = (String)st.nextToken();
services1[i] = n;
Toast.makeText(appointment.this, st.nextToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Can any one please suggest some ideas..

Comment: StringTokenizer is deprecated on Java 6.

Answer (score 9):

Why not use [String.split()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) ?

You can simply do

```
String[] my_array = myStr.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since '|' is a special character in regular expression, we need to escape it.

```
for(String token : result.split("\\|"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(appointment.this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.split](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) or Android's [TextUtils.split](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html) if you need to return [] when the string to split is empty.

From the [StringTokenizer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) API docs:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that
>   is retained for compatibility reasons
>   although its use is discouraged in new
>   code. It is recommended that anyone
>   seeking this functionality use the
>   split method of String or the
>   java.util.regex package instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is a final class, it is by default immutable, which means you cannot make changes to your strings. If you try, a new object will be created, not the same object modified. Therefore if you know in advance that you are going to need to manipulate a `String`, it is wise to start with a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class. There is also [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) for handling threads. Within `StringBuilder` there are methods like `substring()`:

```
substring(int start)
Returns a new String that contains a subsequence of characters currently contained in this character sequence.
```

or `getChars()`:

```
getChars(int srcBegin, int srcEnd, char[] dst, int dstBegin)
Characters are copied from this sequence into the destination character array dst.
```

or `delete()`:

```
delete(int start, int end)
Removes the characters in a substring of this sequence.
```

Then if you really need it to be a String in the end, use the String constructor(s)

```
String(StringBuilder builder)
Allocates a new string that contains the sequence of characters currently contained in the string builder argument.
```

or

```
String(StringBuffer buffer)
Allocates a new string that contains the sequence of characters currently contained in the string buffer argument.
```

Although to understand when to use `String` methods and when to use `StringBuilder`, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725739/correct-way-to-use-stringbuilder) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java) might help. (StringBuilder comes in handy with saving on memory).