# How to SELECTIVELY bold text in a TextView

Tags: java, android, text

I have this statement:

```
s = s +   "Id: " + lc.getID() + "  Name: " + lc.getName() + "\n"
                + "  Phone Number: " + lc.getPhone() + "  Email: " + lc.getEmail() + "\n"
                + "  Description: " + lc.getDescription() + "\n\n"
```

that prints this out:

```
Id: 1  Name: Eric
 Phone Number: 8294038  Email: foo@gmail.com
 Description: Cool guy Eric
```

I want to Bold only the titles (Id, Name, etc).

I tried this:

```
        s = s + Html.fromHtml(" <b> Id: </b>" + lc.getID() + "  <b> Name: </b>" + lc.getName() + "\n"
                + "  Phone Number: " + lc.getPhone() + "  Email: " + lc.getEmail() + "\n"
                + "  Description: " + lc.getDescription() + "\n"
                + "\n\n");
```

But not only does it not bold, but it takes away the new lines (\n). Any ideas on how to get this done? Thanks.

Comment: Try using "<br/>" instead of "\n"

Comment: This worked for the new lines but the <b> </b> still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Html.fromHtml()` returns a `Spanned` object, designed to be put **directly** into a `TextView` or similar widget.

A `Spanned` is not a `String`.

By doing `s = s + Html.fromHtml(...)`, you are saying "please parse this HTML into a `Spanned`, then throw out all the formatting to give me a `String` that I can concatenate onto some other `String`". That's not what you want -- you want to keep the formatting. But a Java `String` does not have formatting, and so ordinary string concatenation has no way to keep it.

Beyond that, as Manishika pointed out, newlines are ignored in HTML anyway, as you use HTML elements for vertical whitespace.

Your options include:

1. Generate a **complete** HTML snippet -- including whatever it is you are trying to concatenate it to -- and then use `Html.fromHtml()` on the entire thing. You may wish to use a template engine (e.g., [jmustache](https://github.com/samskivert/jmustache)) for that, or `String.format()`. Or, use `StringBuilder`, rather than lots of `+` operations (less memory churn, faster performance). Be sure to use `<br/>` or `<p>` for your line breaks/paragraph delimiters.
2. Use `SpannableStringBuilder` to assemble the string and its formatting from component parts.
3. Use `TextUtils.concat(s, Html.fromHtml(...))` instead of `s + Html.fromHtml(...)`, as `concat()` will maintain the spans that implement the formatting. While the implementation of `Spanned` returned by `fromHtml()` is not a `String`, both it and `String` are a `CharSequence`, and hence work with `concat()`.

Comment: Appreciate the answer! Don't appreciate the insults. Nonetheless, thank you for the help!

Comment: @nick: Using `+` for multiple string concatenations is a Java anti-pattern, one that should have been covered wherever you learned Java. BTW, I added a third option to the answer (had it mind when I started the answer, then forgot about it...).

Comment: Could you explain how else to concatenate these strings? Or at least give me a start. Excuse my lack of knowledge

Comment: @nick: Use `StringBuilder`, as noted in the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725739/correct-way-to-use-stringbuilder

Answer (score 0):

It will require a little bit of parsing on your end, but you definitely want to look into [`SpannableStrings`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html).

For example, let's say I have the following string:

```
String s = "How now brown cow";
```

I would then turn it into a `SpannableString` by simply feeding the string to the constructor as follows:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(s);
```

From there you need your stylization with the spanned area.  For this, I'll just use `SubscriptSpan`, though if you wish to make your own you can simply make your own class extending [`CharacterStyle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html) and override the `updateDrawState(TextPaint ds)` method.  The following is how you can set you span:

```
/ *
  * the first argument is the span effect you want, the second and third
  * are the start and end indices, respectively, and the last argument is
  * for setting a flag, which you probably won't need.
  */
ss.setSpan(new SubscriptSpan(), 0, 2, 0);
```

And now you can just put your string straight into the `TextView` and it should appear how you want, like so:

```
myTextView.setText(ss);
```