# On Java 1.7+ should we still need to convert "this string" + "should" + "be" + "joined" using StringBuffer.append for best practices?

Tags: java, stringbuffer

On Java 1.7+ should we still need to convert "this string" + "should" + "be" + "joined" using StringBuffer.append for best practices?

Comment: Since Java 8 you have the possibility to make a list of Strings you want to be joined and use the static method [String.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-).

Comment: Do you mean `StringBuilder()`?

Comment: Actually, there are two classes StringBuffer and StringBuilder, both do concatenation. About the difference between them read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer

Comment: thanks.. this is very informative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) constant expressions (JLS 15.28) like `"this string" + " should" + " be" + " joined"` do not need StringBuilder because it is calculated at compile time into one string `"this string should be joined"`

2) for non-constant expressions compiler will apply StringBuilder automatically. That is, `"string" + var` is equivalent to `new StringBuilder().append("string").append(var).toString();`

We only need to use StringBuilder explicitly where a string is constructed dynamically, like here

```
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (String e : arr) {
        s.append(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// using String concatentation
String str = "this string" + "should" + "be" + "joined";

// using StringBuilder
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("this string");
builder.append("should");
builder.append("be");
builder.append("joined");
String str = builder.toString();
```

Your decision to use raw `String` concatenation versus `StringBuilder` is probably going to depend on the readability and maintainability of your code, rather than performance.  Under the Oracle JVM, using direct `String` concatenation, the compiler will actually use a single `StringBuilder` under the hood.  As a result, *both examples I gave above would have nearly identical bytecode*.  If you find yourself doing many series of raw `String` concatenations, then `StringBuilder` may offer you a performance improvement.  See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725739/correct-way-to-use-stringbuilder) for more information (which was written **after** Java 7 was released).