# Joining string array together, from certain argument, into a string?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Here is my String array containing the following:

"message" "player" "how" "are" "you"

I am wanting to join the "how" "are" "you" part of the String[] and I am currently doing the following:

```
String msg = "";

for (int i = 2; i < args.length; i++)
{
    msg = msg + args[i] + " ";
}

Util.messagePlayer(player, msg);
```

So my question is, is there a better/more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: instead of `String` use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way, everytime you are iterating that array, new String objects are getting created(because [Strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning)), however this one is a short String, so the efficiency loss is not that considerable,still try to use `StringBuilder` instead

```
StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 2; i < args.length; i++)
{
    msg.append(args[i] + " ");
}
Util.messagePlayer(player, msg.toString);
```

For complete details, [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1532483/681929)

Comment: Works, although msg needs to be: `StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();`

Answer (score 0):

`String` objects are immutable ones in Java, hence every time you concatenate two strings, you are creating a new Object this is costly.

Instead, you can use a `StringBuilder`.

More about how to use it is well described here:
[Correct way to use StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725739/correct-way-to-use-stringbuilder)